# Remove zeros in the start and end of a vector

Tags: r

I have a vector like this:

```
x <-  c(0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 5, 0, 0, 3, 2, 7, 0, 0, 0)
```

I want to keep only the elements from position 5 to 11. I want to delete the zeroes in the start and end. For this vector it is quite easy since it is small.

I have very large data and need something in general for all vectors.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this:

```
x[ min( which ( x != 0 )) : max( which( x != 0 )) ]
```

Find index for all values that are not zero, and take the first -`min` and last - `max` to subset `x`.

Answer (score 3):

You can try something like:

```
x=c(0,0,0,0,4,5,0,0,3,2,7,0,0,0)
rl <- rle(x)

if(rl$values[1] == 0)
    x <- tail(x, -rl$lengths[1])
if(tail(rl$values,1) == 0)
    x <- head(x, -tail(rl$lengths,1))

x
## 4 5 0 0 3 2 7
```

Hope it helps,

alex

Comment: Yeah it helps, thanks a lot. But rle function seems to have some limitations.Does good for small data, but not working for large dataset :)

Answer (score 2):

This would also work :

```
x[cumsum(x) & rev(cumsum(rev(x)))]
# [1] 4 5 0 0 3 2 7
```

Answer (score 1):

I would probably define two functions, and compose them:

```
trim_leading <- function(x, value=0) {
  w <- which.max(cummax(x != value))
  x[seq.int(w, length(x))]
}

trim_trailing <- function(x, value=0) {
  w <- which.max(cumsum(x != value))
  x[seq.int(w)]
}
```

And then pipe your data through:

```
x %>% trim_leading %>% trim_trailing
```