# R Remove zeros at the start and end of a column

Tags: r

Expanding on someone else's question here: [Remove zeros in the start and end of a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24009982/remove-zeros-in-the-start-and-end-of-a-vector) ,
how do I do the same in a data table?

Example data:

```
x Date.Time
0 2014-09-25 10:10:00
0 2014-09-25 10:15:00 
0 2014-09-25 10:20:00
0 2014-09-25 10:25:00
4 2014-09-25 10:30:00
5 2014-09-25 10:35:00
0 2014-09-25 10:40:00
0 2014-09-25 10:45:00
3 2014-09-25 10:50:00
2 2014-09-25 10:55:00
7 2014-09-25 11:00:00
0 2014-09-25 11:05:00
0 2014-09-25 11:10:00
0 2014-09-25 11:15:00
```

I would like to transform it into this:

```
x Date.Time
4 2014-09-25 10:30:00
5 2014-09-25 10:35:00
0 2014-09-25 10:40:00
0 2014-09-25 10:45:00
3 2014-09-25 10:50:00
2 2014-09-25 10:55:00
7 2014-09-25 11:00:00
```

The rows with zeros in the x column in the middle are maintained, but the leading and tailing rows containing zero are removed.

I have attempted to use this command, adapted from the original question:

`example[min(which(example$x !=0)):max(which(example$x !=0))]`

but I get the error "undefined columns selected". I can extract the column and carry out the command, but I want to retain the Date.Time relationship.

This is my first question, apologies for formatting/etiquette errors.

Comment: You were almost there! You found the right way to select the rows you need, but forgot a comma in the subsetting. `example[min(which(example$x !=0)):max(which(example$x !=0)),]` should work.

Comment: A note: check if your data are in a data.frame or a data.table. I played around with it, and the code you supplied works on a data.table-object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are simply missing a comma:

```
example[min(which(example$x !=0)):max(which(example$x !=0)),]
```

You need the comma because you need to tell R which columns to use.

For instance:

```
example[1:5, 2:3]
```

Takes rows 1 to 5 and columns 2 to 3.

If you omit the number after the comma you select all columns.