# Replace penultimate non-empty row tail with NA in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
 df <- read.table(tc <- textConnection("
 var1    var2    var3    var4
 1       2       7      NA
 4       4       NA      6
 2       NA      3       NA                
 4       4       4       4              
 1       3      NA      NA"), header = TRUE); close(tc)
```

I want to replace the penultimate non-empty row tails with NAs to give me a new data frame that looks like this:

```
 df <- read.table(tc <- textConnection("
 var1    var2    var3    var4
 1       NA       7      NA
 4       NA      NA      6
 NA       NA      3       NA                
 4       4       NA       4              
 NA       3      NA      NA"), header = TRUE); close(tc)
```

I'm able to identify the location of the penultimate non-empty row tails by using the statement:

```
 penultimate <- function(x) head(tail(x[!is.na(x)], 2),1)
```

My problem is how to now change these to NAs.

Comment: It is not clear how the values are replaced with NAs.  For example in the first column 3 and 5 rows are NA and in the second 1st 3 rows are NA.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what "penultimate non-empty row tail" means?

Comment: @akrun, the replacement is done by row and not column. Notice that in the 1st row of the original data frame, the penultimate non-NA value is 2, which is now replaced with NA in the new data frame. For the 2nd row, the penultimate value in the original data frame is 4, which is now replaced with NA in the new data frame. Get the pattern now?

Comment: I posted a solution.  Please check if that is what you wanted.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik,. penultimate non-empty row tail means the non-NA tail value in each row. E.g the penultimate non-empty row tail in the original data frame for row 1 is  2, for row 2 is 4, for row 3 is 2, for row 4 is 4, for row 5 is 1.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R Remove zeros at the start and end of a column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32372276/r-remove-zeros-at-the-start-and-end-of-a-column)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `apply`

```
penultimate <- function(x) replace(x, head(tail(which(!is.na(x)), 2),1), NA)
t(apply(df, 1, penultimate))
#      var1 var2 var3 var4
#[1,]    1   NA    7   NA
#[2,]    4   NA   NA    6
#[3,]   NA   NA    3   NA
#[4,]    4    4   NA    4
#[5,]   NA    3   NA   NA
```

Or we can use `which` with `arr.ind=TRUE`

```
i1 <- which(!is.na(df), arr.ind=TRUE)
df[i1[!!ave(i1[,2], i1[,1], FUN = function(x) rank(-x)==2),]] <- NA
```

---

If we need to use `dplyr`, the `rowwise` with `do` can get the expected output

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   rowwise() %>%
   do(data.frame(t(penultimate(unlist(.)))))
#  var1  var2  var3  var4
#  <int> <int> <int> <int>
#1     1    NA     7    NA
#2     4    NA    NA     6
#3    NA    NA     3    NA
#4     4     4    NA     4
#5    NA     3    NA    NA
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, as.list(penultimate(unlist(.SD))), .(rn= 1:nrow(df))][, rn := NULL][]
```